Sharing instance of a class between multiple tests running in parallel in Junit5
I'm working on a test framework for a project that consists of multiple APIs. For each of them I have a different client that needs to authorize with different token. Tests are run in parallel.
My solution was creating a class that holds tokens in a map, mapping client to his/her tokens for different services.
public class TokenManager {
    private static final Map<Client, Map<String, Token>> tokens = new EnumMap<>(Client.class);
    
    public static String getToken(Client client, String service) {
        if (isTokenExpired(client, service)) {
            renewToken(client, service);
        }
        return tokens.get(client).get(service).getAccessToken();
}

...and call the getToken() in a @BeforeEach method of a base class that each test then extends, like so
class BaseTest {
    
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        TokenManager.getToken(clientFoo, serviceBar);
    }
}

class SomeTestClass extends BaseTest {
    
   @Override
   void setUp() {
        super.setUp();
        // test-specific setup
    }

    @Test
    void someTest() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test
    void otherTest() {
        assertTrue(false);
    }

My assumption was that an instance of TokenManager class was created once, before a run of all tests (either through maven, or Intellij runner). In reality, it's created for each test class. So tokens are shared between different tests of the same class, but not between tests of different classes. As mentioned before, tests are run in parallel.
My problems are:

Each test class creates new tokens, when I'd like the instance of TokenManager to be created once and supply all tests with proper tokens, that are only refreshed when expired

Once in a while I get NullPointerException stating:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Token.getAccessToken()" because the return value of "java.util.Map.get(Object)" is null
 at TokenManager.getToken(TokenManager.java:57)
 at BaseTest.setUp(BaseTest.java:9)
 at SomeTest.setUp(SomeTest.java:37)



My questions are:

What should I do to force Junit share an instance of TokenManager class between different test classes?

Is there a better solution to this problem?



You can create a JUnit5 extension, but the junit lifecycle doesn't provide for "once before all tests", so you'd still have a token per class. Not sure why this this would be a problem.

Your code isn't thread safe. You need to fix that first. And it's not easy. In general, making tests that are not independent is a bad idea. (i.e. failure in test A can cause test B to fail even though there's nothing wrong with test B, and nothing that test B is testing is bugged. This is what's going to happen with how you're setting things up, and it's really bad - this is why JUnit doesn't work that way)

Make this stuff threadsafe first - it'll involve either synchronized or try (lock) in your getToken method. Or a complete rewrite using threadsafe methods in ConcurrentHashMap and co (you can't make 'if (!valid) makeValid(); return thing;thread safe. Ever. Without lock/synchronized. And it's what yourgetToken` method does).

Only then can you focus on this question. I'm pretty sure what you're saying is incorrect - your test runner does run static stuff only once ever, and junit does have a lifecycle for once  before all, it's called @BeforeAll (user @daniu is wrong). Possibly your parallel test runner is creating multiple JVMs in which case you obviously can't share a single Map instance between JVM instances. You'd need to cook up a separate process that serves as 'token distributor'.

Does this answer your question? In JUnit 5, how to run code before all tests

@rzwitserloot @BeforeAll is run before all test cases in a single test class, not all tests overall which I understand was meant. I may have misinterpreted of course.

@daniu No, you're right, I messed this one up. My apologies!

@murat-karagöz thanks for sharing this question! This is useful for me in other case, as I'd like to make some general set up in "once before all tests" moment. But for this particular problem I'm not sure if it's suitable.

@rzwitserloot you're right, the problem is in thread-safety. When run sequentially, there seems to be only 1 instance of TokenManager and tests from different classes have access to the same tokens map. I'll try to look into it, but there seems to be many factors to consider - thread safety itself (this I guess causes problem 2 from original question), but also the way junit handles concurrency (... and that causes problem 1).  Could you give me a hint where to look for info about coding such "token distributor"?

As a general comment - I wanted to have such a mechanism, because I didn't want to fire too many unnecessary token requests to API. Lots of times, a single class has only 1 test. I don't think it makes tests being dependant on each other, at least use-case-wise. I mean if this mechanism was coded right, then test cases are completely unrelated to each other and don't influence each other. I think about this mechanism as a configuration/framework feature, not a part of the test case itself. Am I wrong?

@zeluzel So you're saying you're actually doing external API calls during the test run; that is almost never a good setup for a test, at least if you're not doing an actual system integration test (which are usually not run via JUnit in my experience). I would suggest you use a @MockBean for which you can mock the external calls into returning you a token as you see fit, and would make your test independent from external systems to be available.

Sorry for late reply. My issue was resolved simply by adding @Synchronized to getToken method. So, as @rzwitserloot pointed out, it was a problem of concurrency... and only of concurrency - instance of TokenManager is indeed created once, before all tests (not @BeforeAll, but rather "before any") and is shared between all test classes.

@daniu I'm a tester, so my project is all about making external API calls during test run ;).

My issue was resolved simply by adding @Synchronized to getToken method. So, as @rzwitserloot pointed out, it was a problem of concurrency, and only of concurrency. Instance of TokenManager is indeed created once, before all tests (not @BeforeAll, but rather "before any") and is shared between all test classes.
